# GLM50C ragnefinder (Bluetooth smart 4) cannot Connect with Windows

Tags: windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, bosch-iot-suite

I am trying to Connect Bosch GLM 50c with Windows Apps and code projects but even if i find the device i cannot connect.

I have tried 3 win-apps (ArCADia CAD software, SiteMaster Building CAD software, GLM transfer software) and 2 projects for this device (in python [here](https://github.com/philipptrenz/BOSCH-GLM-rangefinder) and in C# [here](https://github.com/Scarfsail/BoschGLM50)) but all respond the same.

All can find the device, but when trying to connect, the device seems to be connected and after a while the connection is lost.

However the device works excellent with Android Apps.

Does anyone have any idea? Is it possible for a device to connect with different OS?

Comment: How are you connecting the device? A Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE, sometimes also called Bluetooth smart) device might be visible in the OS bluetooth settings, but BLE is different from Bluetooth classic and does not need to be connected using the settings. The projects using that device are using BLE to connect to that device. If your Win-Apps are not able to connect to BLE devices you have no chance to get it to work

Comment: Looking at the projects you linked to, it appears that the `GLM50c` is a Bluetooth Classic device. This means you will most likely have to do the one-time pairing process manually with your Windows Settings before you run the scripts. The python project uses `pybluez` which was the only option until recently. Python3.9 supports Serial Port Profile on Windows in its `socket` library. The are details comparing the two at: https://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/  It would be helpful if you published some more information about what you are doing. e.g. Code and/or errors

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot for your interest. Yes, the device is already connected and visible to Windows when i try the connection through apps and code projects. However, lets take a look to a python code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple connection project in python.
I posted 2 codes. I have **bolded** the lines where I face the problem.

The bolded line of first code ,calls the **def connect (self, addrport)** function of the second(library) code, and in the bolded line of second code it hangs. The device seems to be connected (it appears the bluetooth symbol on screen) and after a while the connection is lost and exeption is thrown.

I have no idea what the **bt.connect (self._sockfd, addr, port)** does and why it hangs.

GLM_50c.py

---

```
import bluetooth  # install pybluez before importing
import struct
import binascii


class GLMxxC(object):
    device_name = ''
    socket = None
    port = 0x0005  # depends on model type
    bluetooth_address = None
    connected = False
    cmds = {
        'measure':          b'\xC0\x40\x00\xEE',
        'laser_on':         b'\xC0\x41\x00\x96',
        'laser_off':        b'\xC0\x42\x00\x1E',
        'backlight_on':     b'\xC0\x47\x00\x20',
        'backlight_off':    b'\xC0\x48\x00\x62'
    }
    status = {
        0:  'ok',
        1:  'communication timeout',
        3:  'checksum error',
        4:  'unknown command',
        5:  'invalid access level',
        8:  'hardware error',
        10: 'device not ready',
    }

    #Initializing or Constructor
    def __init__(self, bluetooth_address=None):
        if bluetooth_address is None:
            self.find_GLMxxC()
        else:
            self.bluetooth_address = bluetooth_address
        self.connect()

    #Finding the available bluetooth devices   
    def find_GLMxxC(self):
        print('Searching for BOSCH GLMxxC ...')
    
        nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(
            duration=8, lookup_names=True, flush_cache=True, lookup_class=False)
        print('0')
        for index, val in enumerate(nearby_devices):
             addr, name = val
             if 'BOSCH GLM' in name.upper():
                 self.bluetooth_address = addr
                 print('Found ', name.upper(), ' @', self.bluetooth_address)
                 self.device_name = name.upper()
                 if 'GLM50' in self.device_name:
                      self.port = 0x0005
                 return
            
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
```

```
self.socket.connect((self.bluetooth_address, self.port))
```

```
            self.connected = True
        except:
            self.socket.close()
            self.conencted = False

    def measure(self):
        self.socket.send(self.cmds['measure'])
        data = self.socket.recv(1024)
        print('received:', int(binascii.hexlify((data[0]))))
        if self.status[int(binascii.hexlify((data[0])))] == 'ok':
            try:
                # distance to object from top of device
                distance = int(struct.unpack("<L", data[2:6])[0])*0.05
                return distance
            except:
                return -1
        else:
            return -1

    
    def find_bluetooth_services(self):
        services = bluetooth.find_service(address=self.bluetooth_address)
        if len(services) > 0:
            print("found %d services on %s" % (len(services),self.bluetooth_address))
            print(services)
        else:
            print("no services found")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Add argparse in a future.
    try:
        #device = GLMxxC(bluetooth_address='00:13:43:A4:93:07')
        device = GLMxxC()
    except:
        print('No devices GLM100C found')
   
    print('after classes built')
    # connecting can be speeded up when the mac address of the device is known, e.g.:
    # device = GLM100C(bluetooth_address='54:6C:0E:29:92:2F')

    try:
        print("Trying to connect with "+ device.__class__.__name__)
        device.connect()
    except ConnectionError:
        print ('Can\'t connect with ' + device.__class__.__name__)

    # print('')
    #device.find_bluetooth_services()
    # print('')

    if device.connected:
        print('Connected BOSCH '+ device.__class__.__name__+'@',device.bluetooth_address)

        try:
            print('\ntype \'m\' to measure, \n\'lon\' or \'loff\' to turn laser on/off, \n\'bon\' or \'boff\' to turn backlight on/off,\n\'x\' to exit\n')

            while True:
                data = input()
                if data == 'm':
                    distance = device.measure()
                    if distance > 0:
                        print(distance, 'mm from top of device')
                        print(distance+40.0, 'mm from tripod socket')
                        print(distance+110.0, 'mm from back of device')
                elif data == 'lon':
                    device.turn_laser_on()
                elif data == 'loff':
                    device.turn_laser_off()
                elif data == 'bon':
                    device.turn_backlight_on()
                elif data == 'boff':
                    device.turn_backlight_off()
                elif data == 'x':
                    device.close()
                    print('Connection to BOSCH ' + device.__class__.__name__ + ' closed')
                    break

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            device.close()
            print('Connection to '+ device.__class__.__name__+' closed')
    else:
        print('Could not connect to '+ device.__class__.__name__ )
```

---

Here is the *msbt.py* file from python39 Libraries, where the code it hangs.

```
from bluetooth import *
import bluetooth._msbt as bt

bt.initwinsock ()

# ============== SDP service registration and unregistration ============

def discover_devices (duration=8, flush_cache=True, lookup_names=False,
                  lookup_class=False, device_id=-1):
    #this is order of items in C-code
    btAddresIndex = 0
    namesIndex = 1
    classIndex = 2

    try:
        devices = bt.discover_devices(duration=duration, flush_cache=flush_cache)
    except OSError:
        return []
    ret = list()
    for device in devices:
        item = [device[btAddresIndex],]
        if lookup_names:
            item.append(device[namesIndex])
        if lookup_class:
            item.append(device[classIndex])

        if len(item) == 1: # in case of address-only we return string not tuple
            ret.append(item[0])
        else:
            ret.append(tuple(i for i in item))
    return ret


def read_local_bdaddr():
    return bt.list_local()


def lookup_name (address, timeout=10):
    if not is_valid_address (address): 
        raise ValueError ("Invalid Bluetooth address")
    try:
        return bt.lookup_name(address)
    except OSError:
        return None


class BluetoothSocket:
    def __init__ (self, proto = RFCOMM, sockfd = None):
        if proto not in [ RFCOMM ]:
            raise ValueError ("invalid protocol")
    
        if sockfd:
            self._sockfd = sockfd
        else:
            self._sockfd = bt.socket (bt.SOCK_STREAM, bt.BTHPROTO_RFCOMM)
        self._proto = proto

        # used by advertise_service and stop_advertising
        self._sdp_handle = None
        self._raw_sdp_record = None

        # used to track if in blocking or non-blocking mode (FIONBIO appears
        # write only)
        self._blocking = True
        self._timeout = False

    @property
    def family (self):
        return bt.AF_BTH

    @property
   def type (self):
        return bt.SOCK_STREAM

    @property
    def proto (self):
        return bt.BTHPROTO_RFCOMM

    def bind (self, addrport):
        if self._proto == RFCOMM:
            addr, port = addrport

            if port == 0: port = bt.BT_PORT_ANY
            bt.bind (self._sockfd, addr, port)

    def listen (self, backlog):
        bt.listen (self._sockfd, backlog)

    def accept (self):
        clientfd, addr, port = bt.accept (self._sockfd)
        client = BluetoothSocket (self._proto, sockfd=clientfd)
        return client, (addr, port)

    def connect (self, addrport):
        addr, port = addrport
```

```
bt.connect (self._sockfd, addr, port)
```

```
    def send (self, data):
        return bt.send (self._sockfd, data)

    def recv (self, numbytes):
        return bt.recv (self._sockfd, numbytes)

    def close (self):
        return bt.close (self._sockfd)

    def getsockname (self):
        return bt.getsockname (self._sockfd)

    def getpeername (self):
        return bt.getpeername (self._sockfd)

    getpeername.__doc__ = bt.getpeername.__doc__

    def setblocking (self, blocking):
        bt.setblocking (self._sockfd, blocking)
        self._blocking = blocking

    def settimeout (self, timeout):
        if timeout < 0: raise ValueError ("invalid timeout")

       if timeout == 0:
            self.setblocking (False)
        else:
            self.setblocking (True)

        bt.settimeout (self._sockfd, timeout)
        self._timeout = timeout

    def gettimeout (self):    
        if self._blocking and not self._timeout: return None
        return bt.gettimeout (self._sockfd)

    def fileno (self):
        return self._sockfd

    def dup (self):
        return BluetoothSocket (self._proto, sockfd=bt.dup (self._sockfd))

    def makefile (self):
        # TODO
        raise Exception("Not yet implemented")


def advertise_service (sock, name, service_id = "", service_classes = [], \
        profiles = [], provider = "", description = "", protocols = []):
    if service_id != "" and not is_valid_uuid (service_id):
        raise ValueError ("invalid UUID specified for service_id")
    for uuid in service_classes:
        if not is_valid_uuid (uuid):
            raise ValueError ("invalid UUID specified in service_classes")
    for uuid, version in profiles:
        if not is_valid_uuid (uuid) or  version < 0 or  version > 0xFFFF:
            raise ValueError ("Invalid Profile Descriptor")
    for uuid in protocols:
        if not is_valid_uuid (uuid):
            raise ValueError ("invalid UUID specified in protocols")        

    if sock._raw_sdp_record is not None:
        raise OSError("service already advertised")

    avpairs = []

    # service UUID
    if len (service_id) > 0:
        avpairs.append (("UInt16", SERVICE_ID_ATTRID))
        avpairs.append (("UUID", service_id))

    # service class list
    if len (service_classes) > 0:
        seq = [ ("UUID", svc_class) for svc_class in service_classes ]
        avpairs.append (("UInt16", SERVICE_CLASS_ID_LIST_ATTRID))
        avpairs.append (("ElemSeq", seq))

    # set protocol and port information
    assert sock._proto == RFCOMM
    addr, port = sock.getsockname ()
    avpairs.append (("UInt16", PROTOCOL_DESCRIPTOR_LIST_ATTRID))
    l2cap_pd = ("ElemSeq", (("UUID", L2CAP_UUID),))
    rfcomm_pd = ("ElemSeq", (("UUID", RFCOMM_UUID), ("UInt8", port)))
    proto_list = [ l2cap_pd, rfcomm_pd ]
    for proto_uuid in protocols:
        proto_list.append (("ElemSeq", (("UUID", proto_uuid),)))
    avpairs.append (("ElemSeq", proto_list))

    # make the service publicly browseable
    avpairs.append (("UInt16", BROWSE_GROUP_LIST_ATTRID))
    avpairs.append (("ElemSeq", (("UUID", PUBLIC_BROWSE_GROUP),)))

    # profile descriptor list
    if len (profiles) > 0:
        seq = [ ("ElemSeq", (("UUID",uuid), ("UInt16",version))) \
                for uuid, version in profiles ]
        avpairs.append (("UInt16", 
            BLUETOOTH_PROFILE_DESCRIPTOR_LIST_ATTRID))
        avpairs.append (("ElemSeq", seq))

    # service name
    avpairs.append (("UInt16", SERVICE_NAME_ATTRID))
    avpairs.append (("String", name))

    # service description
    if len (description) > 0:
        avpairs.append (("UInt16", SERVICE_DESCRIPTION_ATTRID))
        avpairs.append (("String", description))

    # service provider
    if len (provider) > 0:
        avpairs.append (("UInt16", PROVIDER_NAME_ATTRID))
        avpairs.append (("String", provider))

    sock._raw_sdp_record = sdp_make_data_element ("ElemSeq", avpairs)
#    pr = sdp_parse_raw_record (sock._raw_sdp_record)
#    for attrid, val in pr.items ():
#        print "%5s: %s" % (attrid, val)
#    print binascii.hexlify (sock._raw_sdp_record)
#    print repr (sock._raw_sdp_record)

    sock._sdp_handle = bt.set_service_raw (sock._raw_sdp_record, True)

def stop_advertising (sock):
    if sock._raw_sdp_record is None:
        raise OSError("service isn't advertised, " \
                    "but trying to un-advertise")
    bt.set_service_raw (sock._raw_sdp_record, False, sock._sdp_handle)
    sock._raw_sdp_record = None
    sock._sdp_handle = None

def find_service (name = None, uuid = None, address = None):
    if address is not None:
        addresses = [ address ]
    else:
        addresses = discover_devices (lookup_names = False)

    results = []

    for addr in addresses:
        uuidstr = uuid or PUBLIC_BROWSE_GROUP
        if not is_valid_uuid (uuidstr): raise ValueError ("invalid UUID")

        uuidstr = to_full_uuid (uuidstr)

        dresults = bt.find_service (addr, uuidstr)

        for dict in dresults:
            raw = dict["rawrecord"]

            record = sdp_parse_raw_record (raw)

            if SERVICE_CLASS_ID_LIST_ATTRID in record:
                svc_class_id_list = [ t[1] for t in \
                        record[SERVICE_CLASS_ID_LIST_ATTRID] ]
                dict["service-classes"] = svc_class_id_list
            else:
                dict["services-classes"] = []

           if BLUETOOTH_PROFILE_DESCRIPTOR_LIST_ATTRID in record:
                pdl = []
                for profile_desc in \
                        record[BLUETOOTH_PROFILE_DESCRIPTOR_LIST_ATTRID]:
                    uuidpair, versionpair = profile_desc[1]
                    pdl.append ((uuidpair[1], versionpair[1]))
                dict["profiles"] = pdl
            else:
                dict["profiles"] = []

            dict["provider"] = record.get (PROVIDER_NAME_ATTRID, None)

            dict["service-id"] = record.get (SERVICE_ID_ATTRID, None)

            # XXX the C version is buggy (retrieves an extra byte or two),
            # so get the service name here even though it may have already
            # been set
            dict["name"] = record.get (SERVICE_NAME_ATTRID, None)

            dict["handle"] = record.get (SERVICE_RECORD_HANDLE_ATTRID, None)
    
#        if LANGUAGE_BASE_ATTRID_LIST_ATTRID in record:
#            for triple in record[LANGUAGE_BASE_ATTRID_LIST_ATTRID]:
#                code_ISO639, encoding, base_offset = triple
#
#        if SERVICE_DESCRIPTION_ATTRID in record:
#            service_description = record[SERVICE_DESCRIPTION_ATTRID]

        if name is None:
            results.extend (dresults)
        else:
           results.extend ([ d for d in dresults if d["name"] == name ])
    return results

# =============== DeviceDiscoverer ==================
class DeviceDiscoverer:
    def __init__ (self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```